# Show virtual keyboard when clicking in text input in google Chrome (Windows 7 using touch monitor)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Every browser that I have tried has the following feature: When you click in a text input field the virtual keyboard symbol is revealed below the text input field (when using a touch screen in windows 7). All browsers except chrome. Anyone knows why and have a possible sollution? (Image below is from Internet explorer)

I would like to test a prototype using touch gestures that only works in chrome thats why I would like to use that browser and that browser alone. =)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best extension for Chrome is [Google Input Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab) (made by google)

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found my preffered sollution to my problem using this program hot virtual keyboard
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcYEFk6_5GQ

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-virtual-keyboard/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn?hl=en) in kiosk mode to show a virtual keyboard when focusing inputs. This is the "less worse" I found. I'm also using [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometouch/ncegfehgjifmmpnjaihnjpbpddjjebme) to enable touch gestures.

Answer (score 1):

has anybody luck with a virtual keyboard that works inside an iframe? Nothing I tested worked with 16.04. Even with chrome web security disabled

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a virtual keyboard that works with iframes?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Google Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tippopper-extension/colobklhibekgdbeplpjchcgpagefagn